# Difference between $http.get , $http.post ,$http.put , $http.delete $http.head and $http.jsonp

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular js and web development.
Please help me.

Today i read about $http in angular js but  i am only aware about the get and post methods .

Can Please anyone explain ,me what is  the  Difference between $http.get , $http.post ,$http.put , $http.delete  $http.head and $http.jsonp

all of them and when to use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http#Request_methods

Comment: and for JSONP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An HTTP **GET** request is what you get (pardon the pun) when you enter a URI in your browser or when you click on a link on a web page. Certain HTML elements, like  also generate GET requests. GET requests a resource (usually a web page or an image) from the server. You can pass additional information to a server-side script by adding 'query parameters' after the script, such as example.com?foo&bar=42.

A **POST** request is similar to a GET request. The difference is that any additional information is sent in the body of the request, rather than as part of the URI. You can generate POST requests using  elements in HTML, where the form field values are sent in the request body.

A **HEAD** request is also similar to a GET request, but the server responds only with the HTTP headers; the response body is empty.

A **PUT** request is a way to upload a file to a server. Most servers don't allow PUT requests, because of the security implications.

Similarly, a **DELETE** request will delete a resource on the server. Like PUT, this method is rarely permitted on server for obvious reasons.

source: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?526956-what-are-GET-POST-PUT-and-DELETE-HTTP-request-and-how-to-use-them

For jsonp I would say to take a look at wikipedia explanation. But it's basically a technique that allows you to make cross-domain requests via XMLHttpRequest.