# How to get data from db using angularjs and entity framework in mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am newbie in learning AngularJS. Can anyone help me to understand how to get data from database using angularjs and entity-framework in mvc5.

Let's say we have data table named:
 `tbl_student {rollno, name}`
 and we want all the students data from the database. So what should be the most understandable way for new learners.

Angular-Code

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyModule", []);
myApp.controller("DBcontroller", function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get("AngularController/AllStudents")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.students = response.data
    })
})
```

Html-code in file named "Test.cshtml"

```
<body  ng-app="MyModule">
<table ng-controller="DBcontroller">
     <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>City</th>
             <th>Institute</th>
           </tr>
     </thead>
           <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
             <td>{{ student.Name }}</td>
             <td>{{ student.City }}</td>
             <td>{{ student.Institute }}</td>
          </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
```

In MVC Controller

```
public class AngularController : Controller
{
    // GET: Angular
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult AllStudents()
    {
        using (EducationContext context = new EducationContext())
        {
            var students = context.tbl_Student.ToList();
            return Json(students, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" and on clicking on error it says "The resource cannot be found."

Comment: Take Controller off of `AngularController`.. so it should just be `$http.get("/Angular/AllStudents")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this probably isn't working is because in your `get` you are adding the word *Controller* after *Angular*.

That is unnecessary.

This should work:

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyModule', []);
    myApp.controller('DBcontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/Angular/AllStudents') // added an '/' along with deleting Controller portion
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.students = response.data
        })
    })
```

Comment: now everything is fine, now the reason is that data is displayed on page through post-request but not by get-request. what could be the reason?

Comment: @WASIF sorry, could you clarify what you are trying to ask?

Comment: In angular, $http.get() does not give me data but when I change it to $http.post() it gives me data on display.

Comment: @WASIF maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352106/difference-between-http-get-http-post-http-put-http-delete-http-head-a) will help

Comment: this is fine and it is telling about difference about $http.get() and $http.post() but I want to know how to get data through $http.get(), not by $http.post()

Answer (score 0):

If you add this in web.config file Http Get will also work

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
       <add name="HttpGet"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to change from `$http.get` to `$http.post`

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyModule', []);
myApp.controller('DBcontroller', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('/Angular/AllStudents') // added an '/' along with deleting Controller portion
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.students = response.data
    });
```

});